# Understanding golang date formatting for time package

Tags: go, time, format

So I have the function performing well.

```
func Today()(result string){
    current_time := time.Now().Local()
    result =  current_time.Format("01/02/2006")
    return
}
```

Prints `MM/DD/YYYY` And I thought that it would be more readable if I had a value greater than 12 in the days position to make it clear that it was MM/DD/YYYY so I changed the to following

```
func Today()(result string){
    current_time := time.Now().Local()
    result =  current_time.Format("01/23/2004")
    return
}
```

Which to my chagrin caused bad results. Prints `MM/DDHH/DD0MM`

Realizing my mistake I see that the format is defined by the [reference time](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Format)...

```
Mon Jan 2 15:04:05 -0700 MST 2006
```

I'm wondering if there is any other instances this moment being used as a formatting reference for date times, and if this reference moment has a nickname (like [null island](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Island))?

Comment: If I understand correctly, are you trying to say? you're unable to use `01/23/2004` as format layout. If yes; you're using an incorrect format layout. I recommend you to have a look at time package constant section https://golang.org/pkg/time/#pkg-constants to know more.

Comment: I'm wondering where else this reference time is used and if it has a moniker. I 100% understand why `01/23/2006` yields the results it does.

Comment: This is pure speculation, but I suspect it was originally meant to be more human-readable than, say, `%a %b %e %H:%M:%S %z %Z %Y`, a subtle variant of the [default output format of the POSIX `date` utility](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/date.html#tag_20_30_10). Speculating further, Monday is the first day of the week in many countries, and January is the first month of the year, which is why they're used. 2006 (i.e. `'06`) was the only year that fit the criteria, so it's the 6th item.

Comment: As for the 15, instead of 03, that's probably for the AM/PM bit since the docs specifically mention "PM".

Comment: @ChronoKitsune that is the belief I have. Just I did a search around; come across this post https://groups.google.com/d/msg/golang-nuts/806le5R6gEc/iYbOz5z6ruwJ

Answer (score 2):

The values in a date string are not arbitrary. You can't just change `02` to `03` and expect it to work.  The date formatter looks for those specific values, and knows that `1` means month, `2` means day of month, etc.

Changing `01/02/2006` to `01/23/2004` is like changing a human-readable form that says `First Name: ______ Last Name: ______` to one that says `First Name: ______ Ice Cream: ______`.  You can't expect anyone to know that `Ice Cream` should mean `Last Name`.

### The name

The only name provided for this is "reference time", [here](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Parse):

> Parse parses a formatted string and returns the time value it represents. The layout defines the format by showing how **the reference time**, defined to be
>
> ```
> Mon Jan 2 15:04:05 -0700 MST 2006
> ```

and [here](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#pkg-constants):

> These are predefined layouts for use in Time.Format and Time.Parse. **The reference time** used in the layouts is the specific time:
>
> ```
> Mon Jan 2 15:04:05 MST 2006
> ```
>
> which is Unix time 1136239445. Since MST is GMT-0700, **the reference time** can be thought of as
>
> ```
> 01/02 03:04:05PM '06 -0700
> ```
>
> To define your own format, write down what **the reference time** would look like formatted your way; see the values of constants like ANSIC, StampMicro or Kitchen for examples. The model is to demonstrate what the reference time looks like so that the Format and Parse methods can apply the same transformation to a general time value.

To specify that you're talking about Go's reference time, I'd say "Go's reference time." Or to be blatantly obvious, "Go's time.Parse reference time."

---

As an aside, your function can be greatly shortened:

```
func Today() string {
    return time.Now().Local().Format("01/02/2006")
}
```